# A variable in for loop is not identifiable rather than it is declared and initialize in loop

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-room, observers

I am getting list from room database and in for loop when i declared a variable and intialize but it is not identifiable in for loop.

[code image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIRku.png)

I declared the variable outside the for loop this error is gone. but then spinner only showing last item of the list.

Answer (score 3):

You are a stackoverflow beginner so you might not have known this, but, for next time please paste your code into the question. Don't screenshot code.

To answer your question, you have an extra semicolon. 
Change to

```
for (int position = 0; position < products.size() - 1; position++)
{
    // Etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove "**;**" which is at the end of `for` loop line

Define `ArrayAdatper` at top

```
ArrayAdatper<String> aa;
```

in `onChanged` method after loop add below line:

```
if(aa != null) {
   aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but i solved this by using iterator.

```
    list = new ArrayList<Product>();
    product = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Views
    Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.add_sale_spinner);


    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProductViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getAllProduct().observe(this, new Observer<List<Product>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Product> products) {
            //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the bank name list
            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: "+products.size()+ "Fdsfsdfds");
            Iterator<Product> iterator = products.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                Product obj = iterator.next();
                list.add(obj);
                product.add(obj.getProductName().toString());
            }
        }
    });
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, product);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(aa);
```